# Why do my apps go to my Launch pad instead of to my ITunes where I can sync the with my IPod

Tags: osx-lion, portable-apps, launchpad

When I download an app, some go to the Launchpad and some go to my application folder. I need them to go to iTunes so that I can sync them with my iPod. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Apps that go to the Launchpad are **Mac apps**, that is, for your desktop computer. You download them from the Mac App Store, an app *on your Mac* which has this icon:

[image]

You **can't** sync Mac apps with your iPod.

To get apps for your iPod, buy them in iTunes or open the App Store *on your iPod,* it is the app with this icon:

[image]